# Display Posts at certain resolution

Tags: php, wordpress, screen-resolution

I am running a Wallpaper site. I have images of different resolution. I want to change the wallpapers with the visitor's screen resolution. Like if someone visit through mobile he will only be able to see mobile's wallpaper or if someone visit through laptop then it detect the screen and show only those wallpapers which are relevant to his screen.
Following Codes I tried,

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['screen_check']))
{
 echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
 document.location=\"$PHP_SELF?screen_check=done&Width=\"+screen.width+\+screen.height;
 </script>";
}
else 
{    
   if(isset($_GET['Width']>1024)) {
 function get_categories( $args = '' ) {
$defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => 'laptop' );
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

$taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];
   if(($_GET['Width']>768)) {
 function get_categories( $args = '' ) {
$defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => 'ipad' );
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

$taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];
 }
 else {
 function get_categories( $args = '' ) {
$defaults = array( 'taxonomy' => 'mobile' );
$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

$taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];;
 }
     }
}
?>
```

Any help would be really appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Okay, Let me edit this with the codes which I tried

Comment: PHP can't detect screen sizes/resolutions. You need to use media queries and/or JS for this. Bootstrap it.

Comment: Is it possible to show posts or hide posts with the Bootstrap ?